# Check if it's a users first time on a certain part of my app

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

When it is a users first time visiting a certain part of my web app I want to present a brief modal FAQ to them. We are using .Net MVC on this app, so I know I can accomplish something similar to this using cookies in Javascript with a long expiration date. But, I'm curious if there is a better way to implement this since cookies can be cleared from the browser by the user. I would guess C# or razor would provide me with a more elegant solution. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The problem with cookies is that they expire and wont be a proper solution, but a easy one

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm really not wanting to go that route.

Comment: Is the user authenticated or an anonymous user?

Comment: Other way to store it is in the DB you use for the app

Comment: @wgraham The user is authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is authenticated, why not store this information server-side (like in a database)? Then you can communicate the "flag" to the View (via the Model or ViewBag) so it can decide whether or not to prompt with the FAQ.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool isUsersFirstTime = IsFirstTime(); // Do something to read this value from the database
    if (isUsersFirstTime)
    {
        UpdateFirstTimeFlag(); // Do something to update this value in the database
    }

    ViewBag.FirstTimeUser = isUsersFirstTime;
}
```

Then in your view, something like (assuming Razor syntax):

```
@if (ViewBag.FirstTimeUser)
{
    <div>Here's the modal FAQ</div>
}
```

Obviously, if you're implementing more of an MVVM approach, you'll want to put the `FirstTimeUser` property in the ViewModel and reference it in the view with `Model.FirstTimeUser`.

Comment: I figured this would be the better solution. Would you be able to provide a short example of how to implement that? I'm still very new .Net MVC. Thanks

Comment: Done. If you need some more help regarding the ViewBag, check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

Comment: Awesome link and response, much appreciated!